# Set an List<T> item as empty if returned row is NULL

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I need to populate a `List<string>` but when my query returns a null value, no empty string is created in this List.

```
var maskObj = (from m in context.sistema_DocType_Index
               join n in context.sistema_Indexes on m.indexId equals n.id
               where m.id == docTypeId
               select new maskModel
               {
                    mask = n.mask
               }).ToList();


return Content(""+maskObj.Count());
```

If this query returns 3 rows, and all of them are `NULL`, I need 3 empty strings in the list.
Is there any way I can achieve this?

I understand that for Sql Server, NULL is an absence of value. Even NULL == NULL returns false, so how could I proceed?

Comment: what about to add 'where n.mask is not null'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want something like the following:

```
mask = n.mask ?? string.Empty
```

This uses the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) to use `string.Empty` if `n.mask` is null.

The SQL generated by entity framework should be similar to this:

```
COALESCE(MASK, '')
```

My answer assumes that you are talking about `mask` being `null` when you say "If this query returns 3 rows, and all of them are NULL".

Answer (score -1):

Add another where clause to your query.

```
.Where(maskModel => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(maskModel));
```

Comment: That's not what the OP wants: He doesn't want to exclude empty rows, he wants to have empty entries for them.

Comment: Looks like you're right. I'll go spend some time on the stackexchange for reading comprehension.